# Rails redirect and routing with dynamic values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I need to redirect a user back to a specific page with a dynamic id after registering. When I go to mydomain.com/registrations/11 it pulls up the user account for id 11. But when I do a new registration, the `redirect_to` line goes to mydomain.com/registrations without any id. How can I make it go to the id that it created for the user?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Registrations Controller:**

```
  # GET /registrations
  def index
    @registrations = Registration.all
  end
  end

  # GET /registrations/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /registrations/new
  def new
    @registration = Registration.new
    @level = Level.find_by id: params["level_id"]
  end

  # POST /registrations
  def create
    @registration = Registration.new registration_params.merge(email: params['registration']['email'],
                                                               card_token: params['registration']['card_token'])
    raise "Please, check registration errors" unless @registration.valid?
    @registration.process_payment(params['registration']['email'], params['registration']['card_token'])
    @registration.save
    redirect_to @registration, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.'
  end
private
    def stripe_params
      params.permit :stripeEmail, :stripeToken
    end
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_registration
      @registration = Registration.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def registration_params
    params.require(:registration).permit(:level_id, :firstname, :lastname, :phone, :email, :card_token)
  end
```

**Routes:**

```
  get 'registrations/:id' => 'registrations#show'
  get 'registrations/new' => 'registrations#new'
  get 'registrations' => 'registrations#index'
```

**Edit:**

I was able to make the change of using `save!` to show the exception and work through a few errors. Now I can't figure out this issue with Stripe.

Error: Stripe::CardError (Cannot charge a customer that has no active card):

My Registration model looks like this:

```
  def process_payment(email, card_token)
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create email: email,
                                       card: card_token

    Stripe::Charge.create customer: customer.id,
                          amount: level.price*100,
                          description: level.name,
                          currency: 'usd'

  end
```

Comment: `@registration.save` may be failing without telling you; change that to `@registration.save!` so it will raise an exception in that case.

Comment: Thanks Robert, this showed me a couple errors I needed to fix. But I'm down to one more I can't figure out. See code above.

Comment: @RobertNubel any suggestions?

Comment: `redirect_to @registration` will redirect to /registrations if there is an error on @registration.  Take a look at that object and see what is in `@registration.errors`

Comment: @TreyCopeland: I would open a new question for that issue. I'd wager the  error means what it says, and your card_token -- for whatever reason -- isn't valid. Make sure that `Stripe::Customer.create` is returning an object without any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Raising an exception should not be a part of the normal flow of your application. This is idiomatically correct way to deal with user input in a controller:

```
def create
  @registration = Registration.new(create_params)

  if @registration.save
    redirect_to @registration
  else 
    render :new
  end

end 

def create_params
  registration_params.merge(
     email: params['registration']['email'],
     card_token: params['registration']['card_token']
  )
end
```

When dealing with payments my experience is that it usually is better to create the order or whatever and mark it as unpaid and then collect payment in a separate step. It makes the whole experience a lot less frustrating for users as they don't lose whatever form data they might have filled in if you have to go through a credit card payment portal for example.

It also makes the application logic easier since you don't have to wrap every checkout step in transactions and makes repeated payment attempts or split payments easy to implement.